# removing a specific string from a string and the next string after a space

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a string @"ABC 1.23 bla bla bla" from which i have to remove the @"ABC" string and after that the string @"1.23". The problem is that the text @"1.23" varies .. it could be @"1.55" etc. How can i remove the string @"ABC" and the next word after space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, or you can do that in several ways using NSString methods.

1. use `componentsSeparatedByString` and pass a space; your string will be split in an array at word boundaries; then you use `componentsJoinedByString:` ignoring the first two elements of the array;
2. you can use twice in succession `rangeOfString:` passing a space in; the first time it will find the space after ABC; the second time, it will find the space after 1.23 (or whatever); then you get the `substringFromIndex:` starting at that position.

Regular expression would give you much more options, but it would be a steeper curve, if you have never used regex in ObjC. Have a look at [RegExKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html) if you are interested.